# What should I think of when choosing readability test?

Tags: readability

I'm thinking of doing some measurements on readability in various tasks, but looking through available readability tests was somewhat like falling down a rabbit hole. What are the most used ones, and are there any especially well used on academic text and papers?

Comment: There are no good readability tests. Period. If all you need is numbers, use any convenient one. But if you want them to represent something about actual readability, figure out what that actually means first.

Answer (score 1):

[This pdf](http://www.corestandards.org/assets/E0813_Appendix_A_New_Research_on_Text_Complexity.pdf) summarizes some of the main pros and cons of most of the major readability tests. Flesch-Kincaid is probably the most commonly used, since it's easy to calculate and has been around a long time.

As @jlawler said, there are no "good" tests of readability. Some texts which are relatively easy to read might have long sentences or long words, but talk about relatively simple, everyday things. Because of the long sentence and long word length, they might score very high on a readability test. Likewise, you could probably talk about really complex, abstract things using short sentences, and score very low on the readability test. Just because you "write at a 12th grade level" does not mean you're a good writer, it just means you write really long sentences with really big words. Most good books are somewhere between a 5th and 10th grade level.